# Cant connect to Postgresql database after role has been created

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu

I have this little script for database initialization and role creation:

```
create database myDb encoding 'utf8';

\connect myDb;

create role :user_username with LOGIN NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE inherit password :user_password;

grant all privileges on database myDb to :user_username;

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS mySchema AUTHORIZATION :user_username;
```

Which i am calling from ubuntu like this:

> psql $myConnection -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -v user_password='myPassword' -v user_username=myUsername  -f '/scripts/initializedatabase.pgsql'

The script in docker logs reports this - [image: Docker report]

After that i try to test the connection with the database using the newly created role like this:

> psql postgresql://myUsername:myPassword@myServer/myDb -c '\q'

And get the following error:

> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myUsername"

This problem started when i replaced the username from being a constant, to being passed in as a variable. Any thoughts on what the issue might be?

EDIT:

For further clarification, this is what pgAdmin4 shows that myUsername has Security Priviliges on this database

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that when creating roles, any uppercase chars will be converted to lowercase chars :)

Connecting with myusername instead of myUsername fixed this